# Use htaccess to redirect subdomain to folder with Laravel

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite, directory, subdomain

I have my websites on a remote server, which I cannot access so my only way is using .htaccess files.

The directory structure looks like this:

```
/public_html/
└── _sub/
│    └── abc/
├── folder1/
├── folder2/
└── folder3/
```

Which generates a subdomain abc.domain.com., other folders are accessible from www.domain.com/folder1, etc. Now I copied Laravel 5 to the /_sub/abc/ folder, so I can access it with abc.domain.com/public. But I need to access the Laravel without /public/ in the URL with all the routes working. I tried couple of examples in here but they failed to work with the routes like abc.domain.com/auth/login

htaccess in the public is the Laravel 5 default:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/%1/$1 [R,L]
```

Then, for request **sub.domain.com/test** you will redirect to **http://domain.com/sub/test**.

I've not tested this yet, but if something won't work, please, let me know.